# Cusor won't react to hyperlinks when using Safari

Tags: macos, safari, mojave, bug, cursor

**Problem Descriptions**:

Normally when hovering the mouse cursor on a hyperlink, the cursor turns into a little hand, and the link will show the CSS hover effect. But a weird Safari bug kept this from happening.

It's been almost 4 months since I first encounter this issue. Finally I found the *potential cause*:

1. Enter Safari full-screen mode.
2. Click any website from Bookmarks (including Favorites).
3. In the opened website, turn on and off the Bookmark Sidebar once.
4. From now on, any website that opened from Bookmarks won't trigger hover effect.

Here's the same in action:

[image]

---

**What I've tried to solve this**:

1. Empty cache, clear history, remove all plugins, delete relevant plist file, quit all the other apps, but to no avail.
2. Installed latest Safari Technology Preview, repeat step 1, but to no avail.
3. Created another admin account, problem persists.
4. Repaired disk permission in Recovery Mode, didn't fix the issue.

---

I am using a MacBook Pro 15, 2018, running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F203). Safari version 12.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been testing for a day, [Safari Safari Technology Preview Release 86](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/) seems fixed this issue.

The problem might be related to this:

> Pointer Events
>
> - Added support for chorded button interactions
> - Updated to fire `pointerout` and `pointerleave` events after firing `pointercancel`

Not sure when the public version of Safari will be fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Believe it or not, Photoshop is the culprit here.

Turn Photoshop off and the hand will appear....it has something to do with assigning shortcuts to different apps...

Anyway thats what happens to me...once I reboot PS, the cursor turns to a hand for a while...then goes back to not appearing...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Dang, I'll be a monkey's aunt!    That was it: quitted PS 2021 and The Hand came back!

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day! After closing Photoshop, cursor changes immediately worked

Comment: Closing the Creative Cloud process from Activity Monitor can also be the fix - it's not just Photoshop. Thanks Adobe!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari_release_notes/safari_12_1_release_notes) that would indicate this has been fixed, so it's likely a new bug. I don't do Mac OS development, but for this to work, Safari has to tell the OS ['hey, change the mouse pointer when you're over this area.'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor/1524603-closedhand)

Some things you might try:

- [Reset NVRAM and/or PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)
- If you have multiple monitors, unplug all but the primary one, and restart the system.
- [Change the size of the mouse pointer](https://superuser.com/questions/311458/how-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-on-a-mac); that might force the pointer system to reset.
- [Reinstall the OS](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac) (Bonus: [this reinstalls Safari](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204416).)
- Consider updating the firmware on the monitors you have. (Instructions and links will be manufacturer-specific.)

Update: Looks like it's [settable via CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820979/css-cursorpointer-in-mac-safari-doesnt-work), so you've probably got a mix of buggy javascript, CSS, and maybe a bug in Safari. [Here's a JSFiddle that illustrates how it works.](https://jsfiddle.net/czsk8f20/)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just tried reset NVRAM and change the cursor size without connecting external monitor, but it's still not fixed. Since this only happens when Safari is in full screen mode, not sure if it is a JS or CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the culprit, as said from Simon, it is the Photoshop, just quit your photoshop and the cursor will be fine

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  How is this answer any different than the answers already provided?  Answers should not be just confirming another answer worked for you.  See [answer] for additional important info. - From Revew